# Node.js : Connect router middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) for Node.js but having a problem getting the router middleware to do exactly as I want it to.

Specifically, I want to be able to fill the req.params object with the search term portion of a URL, for example

http://www.google.com/search?q=Search

would return `req.params = { "q" : "Search" }`

I'd prefer to have one setup, where I could do something like :

`router.get('/user?:userid&:fullname&:emailaddress', function(req, res) {...`

so that I could access check the access for each search term and then respond accordingly.

Is there a way to do this in Connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really answer that will solve your problem using Connect. But I think you should be using [Express](http://expressjs.com/)(by same author TJ) which uses Connect under the covers, but is way more powerful.

> Sinatra inspired web development
>   framework for node.js -- insanely
>   fast, flexible, and sexy

When using Express achieving this is really easy as shown with app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
        app         = express.createServer();

app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.query);
});

app.listen(3111);
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/so/6513101$ curl -v "http://localhost:3111/search?q=a&y=b"
* About to connect() to localhost port 3111 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3111 (#0)
> GET /search?q=a&y=b HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost:3111
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 17
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
{"q":"a","y":"b"}
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working for me in a browser. I just did the exact same thing, but on port 80, and it responds with "cannot get blah blah blah". Scratch that, I'm an idiot.

Comment: http://localhost/search?q=a&y=b should work. you need to specify the /search part.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question on how to do this with connect.

Comment: @Tom I know :$. I should have said that in my answer, but then again express is addon for connect by the same author. You should really be using that instead!

Comment: A very good reason to use connect over express is that express doesn't support http2 (currently) and connect does. https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/issues/100#issuecomment-142515052

Comment: lol @cchamberlain back then it did not support http2. I think the down-vote is a bit harsh. I am the only person to answer him you only down-vote my answer. If you wrote the correct answer also it would be a little bit more justified to down-vote...